# Can anyone help we with these Xcode errors?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to make an app for my church and am watching a bunch of YT tutorials but I'm getting a lot of errors:[image]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

  @IBAction func Website(sender AnyObject) {

    if let url = NSURL(string: :"http://www.sermonaudio.com/source_detail.asp?sourceid=cfbc1")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url) {
    }

    var userUid: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      getVideo(videoCode: "qS6tvqL1N24")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func goToCreateUserVC(){
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "Feed", sender: nil)
    }
    func goToFeedVC() {
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "Feed", sender: nil)
    }
    func getVideo(videoCode:String!)
    {
      let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoCode)")
      myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "SignUp" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? UserVC {
          if userUid != nil {
            destination.userUid = userUid
          }
          if emailField.text != nil {
            destination.emailField = emailField.text
          }
          if passwordField.text != nil {
            destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
          }
        }
      }
    }

    @IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any){
      if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:
          { (user,error) in
            if error == nil {
              if let user = user {
                self.userUid = user.uid
                self.goSignUpVC()
              }
            } else {
              self.goToCreateUserVC()
            }
        });
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not your personal help desk. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO :) please post your code in the question next time, and you can embed your image file as well to help us see your question more easily.

You forgot to add an ":"
`Website(sender: AnyObject)`

On the next line down from that, you put your "{" one line down too far. It needs to go at the end of the if statement, not after the `UIApplication.sharedApplication....`

There are a couple of other punctuation errors too.

When you see an error saying "override can only be used in a class" that typically means you forgot a closing brace somewhere (which you did). You can select the whole program then do "Editor -> Structure -> Re-indent" which will help you to see where the scope issue is (this is how I fixed the override issue).

Make sure to read and pay attention to your error messages.. one of them clearly tells you that you are missing the "{" after your if statement, and when you see "expected expression" that means that whatever you wrote was gibberish to Swift (meaning you had a typo most likely, or left something incomplete).

I went ahead and edited your question for you, and fixed your code. I have not used *hardly any* of the stuff you are using (I program games), but I simply followed the directions Xcode gave me (the ones with the dot in the center tell you exactly how to fix it):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

  @IBAction func Website(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let url = URL(string: "http://www.sermonaudio.com/source_detail.asp?sourceid=cfbc1") {
      UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
  }
  var userUid: String!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    getVideo(videoCode: "qS6tvqL1N24")
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  func goToCreateUserVC(){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Feed", sender: nil)
  }
  func goToFeedVC() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Feed", sender: nil)
  }
  func getVideo(videoCode:String!)
  {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoCode)")
    myWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
  }
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SignUp" {
      if let destination = segue.destination as? UserVC {
        if userUid != nil {
          destination.userUid = userUid
        }
        if emailField.text != nil {
          destination.emailField = emailField.text
        }
        if passwordField.text != nil {
          destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any){
    if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
      FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:
        { (user,error) in
          if error == nil {
            if let user = user {
              self.userUid = user.uid
              self.goSignUpVC()
            }
          } else {
            self.goToCreateUserVC()
          }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Also, it looks like this is older Swift code, hence why you are getting errors. Try to look for tutorials written in Swift 3 (or download an older Xcode).

Tutorials are great, but they seldom teach you how to solve problems. That is when you have to rely on the debugger and Xcode errors. Try searching here for your errors, and if you still struggle with it then you can always post a question :P

Good luck with your app!

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! im getting and arror and a yellow error still the FIRAuth.auth keeps saying it had been renamed Auth but if i do Auth.auth it says cannot use optinal chaining on optinal value of type "auth"



the yellow error is towards the top UIApplication.shared.openURL has an error it says please use openURL:options:completionHandler: instead but idk what that means

Comment: I don't have firebase so I can't help with that. Try searching for an answer, and if you can't get it then post a new question with the firebase tag, so people can help out :P @PanDuhh